# What is the difference between "waked" and "woke"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, past-tense

> **He woke suddenly** and completely. It was four o'clock, the hour at which his father had always called him to get up and help with the milking. Strange how the habits of his youth clung to him still! Fifty years ago, and his father had been dead for thirty years, and yet **he waked** at four o'clock in the morning. He had trained himself to turn over and go to sleep, but this morning it was Christmas, he did not try to sleep.

an excerpt from *Christmas Day in the Morning* by Pearl S Buck.

Why the writer doesn't use the word 'woke' in the 3rd line? And he instead uses 'waked'?

Comment: I'd like to refer you to a question on our related StackExchange, ELU.  It may be a little more advanced and detailed than you are looking for, but this is a comprehensive answer to your question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221905/past-tense-of-wake-is-there-a-difference-between-waked-and-woke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pearl S Buck was a woman, so your question should ask why **she** used 'waked'. 'Woke' and 'waked' are both possible choices as the past tense of 'wake'. 'Waked' is seen by some as old-fashioned in modern speech and writing. However, Pearl S Buck was born in 1892, to parents born in the 1850s, and wrote 'Christmas Day in the Morning' in 1955, when she was aged 63.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Why would she use woke in one instance and waked in another one? Is there any significance to this?

Comment: @Arnelius She may just have liked variation to avoid repetition. This can be taken too far, when it becomes a writing fault known as 'elegant variation'.